# dnsmasq giving out IPs in the static range

Tags: networking, dhcp, dnsmasq

I have the following in my dnsmasq.conf:

```
dhcp-range=set:red,10.1.1.2,10.1.1.69,72h,static
dhcp-range=set:blue,10.1.1.70,10.1.1.100,72h,static
dhcp-range=set:white,10.1.1.101,10.1.1.200,12h
dhcp-range=10.1.1.201,10.1.1.250,12h
```

I would have thought that the first two ranges would be off limits to anyone not in the hosts file, i.e. reserved for static IP reservations.

However, when I add a random device in the network, it seems to assign an IP in the red range for example, even though there is no static IP reservation for it.  I would have expected an IP to be assigned in the 10.1.1.101 to 10.1.1.250 range.

Does this feature work differently than I expect?

Answer (score 2):

*Old post but I'll give this a go....*

This is because all ranges have the same subnet ..

If eth0 was 10.1.1.1 then it would provide addresses within 10.1.1.2 to 10.1.1.254 that came in through that interface.
This is why all new machines get addresses within that lower (red) range.

But if you had a second physical interface (eth1/wlan0 on 10.1.2.1) then all requests coming in through that; would be given addresses within the 10.1.2.x range, *if configured that way*. This is the only way I know of; of separating traffic *easily* with firewall rules etc.

Because all ranges have the same subnet; dnsmasq is just assigning IPs that are within its own listening interfaces network . 10.1.1.x

In `man dnsmasq` about dhcp-ranges
it states 
`If you have more than one network, you will need to repeat this for each network on which you want to supply DHCP service.`. This to me; means another physical interface and naming them by colour is how I distinguish networks, by using different coloured cables. :)

Reading more into the dnsmasq documentation, I think /etc/hosts is used as part of the nameserver and not DHCP assignment as static IP's usually require a machine name or MAC address to function correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The post is even older now, but I just ran into this myself...

If a beginning and end address is used:

```
dhcp-range=set:red,10.1.1.2,10.1.1.69,static
```

Addresses will be handed out, sometimes even on the wrong subnet.

Instead, try only a network address and a subnet mask:

```
dhcp-range=set:red,10.1.1.0,static,255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to explicitly define static ranges in your `dnsmasq.conf` if they belong to a subnet defined in `dhcp-range`: simply define static leases using `dhcp-host` (e.g., `dhcp-host=[MAC address],[IP address]`. Defining static ranges is only needed if you want to assign static IP addresses in a subnet where you do not also assign dynamic IP addresses.

From the [man page](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html):

> Addresses allocated like this [i.e., using `dhcp-host`] are not constrained to be in the range given by the `--dhcp-range` option, but they must be in the same subnet as some valid `dhcp-range`. For subnets which don't need a pool of dynamically allocated addresses, use the "static" keyword in the `--dhcp-range` declaration.

So, to assign `10.1.1.70` as a static IP address to a machine with MAC address `00:11:22:33:44:55` with a 72 hour lease and tag it with `blue`, use:

```
dhcp-range=10.1.1.201,10.1.1.250,12h
dhcp-host=00:11:22:33:44:55,set:blue,10.1.1.70,72h
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers correctly point out that defining static ranges on the same subnet as a dynamically allocated range is not usually necessary. However, defining more ranges to use with the tag system allows flexibility in configuring the network, and makes it especially easy to change settings for a group of hosts.

The man page says that defining multiple ranges for the same subnet is always allowed. However, I think the config posted in the OP's question is invalid, for 2 reasons:

1. In a dhcp-range line, it is invalid to set both an end-address to the range, and the static mode. The general form of the dhcp-range option is `dhcp-range=[tag:<tag>[,tag:<tag>],][set:<tag>,]<start-addr>[,<end-addr>|<mode>[,<netmask>[,<broadcast>] ]][,<lease time>]`. To my reading, the `|` implies that setting both an `<end-addr>` and the `static` mode is invalid. Even setting the range implicitly by using a network size parameter on the start-addr, as mentioned elsewhere in the man page (e.g. 10.1.1.2/25), was not accepted by `dnsmasq --test`. It seems the static mode keyword is meant as a substitute for the range parameter, and can't be used to define static ranges.
2. To apply dhcp-range settings for particular host(s) *within* a subnet, tags should be `set` in the dhcp-host definition lines, then only referenced in the dhcp-range line. E.g. in my setup, I wanted known hosts to have a longer lease time than unknown ones. The man page says that the "known" tag is set automatically for any host connecting that matches a dhcp-host config. We can use this as follows, taking advantage of the fact that DNSMasq will apply the setting that's more specific (the tag: line), if it applies.

```sh
# Default lease range, with 12h max lease time.
dhcp-range=10.1.1.201,10.1.1.250,12h

# For known hosts, set a 72h lease time.
# - the "known" tag is set whenever a host matches a dhcp-host directive. 
# - other tags could be set in dhcp-host lines using e.g. set:red.
dhcp-range=tag:known,10.1.1.2,static,72h
```